# How do you output audio into a microphone in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, macos

I'm working on a Mac app for personal use that will play sound files into the microphone so that if I'm on a web based phone call or audio chat, I can play sounds from the app into the call.

I have the audio file loaded up and playing, but I still need to get to play into the microphone rather than my speakers. I've Googled this for hours and can find nothing.

How would one go about playing an audio file into the microphone in a Mac OS X (or iOS for that matter) app?

Comment: You can't play audio "to" a microphone. A microphone is an input device. You can only play audio to an output device. Should I make an answer out of that? Vote up if you think so ;-) The real answer to his question would be very lengthy as s/he'd need to implement a new CoreAudio input device which forwards data from a CoreAudio Output device to which s/he's playing the audio file. Of course, the phone call app must be playing along and accept input from a specific input "device".

Comment: Not to discourage you from doing this yourself, but there are existing programs for this: [Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower), [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/).